Find Vector Quaternions in Reference Frame 3D
What I know:
Vector N (start and end coordinates wrt reference frame, but I also know its direction in a frame with origin in the vector origin, but same orientation as reference frame)
What I want to find:
The quaternion (or rotation matrix) with respect to the reference frame, that would align axis z of origin frame with vector N.
Tried to add a clean drawing - with origin frame O; frame P as a frame with its origin in origin of N, and an option imaginary way of going from the z-axis of frame O to N. I know there are multiple ways to rotate, but just put it there as a visual representation
I saw other similar problems, but they seem to always want to find the angle between the 2 vectors, which is not quite what I am looking for, or maybe I am, but didn't understand completely. Because I don't care about the angle of rotation on the plane that contains the 2 vectors, I care about the final orientation wrt to the reference frame. Also, the 2 vectors might not even be in the same plane. I might be just misunderstanding the difference, so if someone would explain in easy terms, would also appreciate.

A rotation (or a suitably applied quaternion) takes one right-handed orthonormal frame to another. You specified that the starting frame is the usual ${\mathbf{i,j,k}}$. What is the final frame? The vector $N$ does not make a frame by itself. You need to specify a right.handed orthonormal triplet. And once you do, you already have the rotation matrix.

The problem is exactly that $N$ belongs to infinitely many such orthonormal frames, each corresponding to a different rotation. All those rotation differ from each other by postcomposing with a rotation about $N$. After all, you can spin the 3D-world while keeping $N$ fixed.

@JyrkiLahtonen that is indeed one of the peculiarities. That N vector was calculated as a normal to a surface, so I guess one thing I could add is 2 tangent vectors to same surface at same point, but I felt like that would be restricting. Afterall, I don't really care about x and y axes. But if there isn't an easy solution to the initial problem, how would the solution go with the added tangent axes?

@JyrkiLahtonen I guess if i do add the 2 tangents, I would end up with an identity matrix (reference frame) and another frame, which would have the directions vx, vy, vz(=N) expressed in the reference frame, and origin p = px,py,pz expressed in reference frame. i guess that implies that the transformation matrix is a 4x4 defined as [vx,vy,vz,p]? from which i can find the quternions. is this the correct logic?

You can get a frame of the required type by picking a random basis including $N$, and the running Gram-Schmidt on it. Fix handedness afterwards, if/when needed. But then you have no control where the $x$ and $y$-directions land. That may be fine, of course. But if there is some noteworthy special direction on the surface, you may want to include that.

Ok, I missed that you want an affine transformation. Yeah, then you need a 4x4 matrix. Augment all the positions (and the fourth column) with $1$ as the fourth component is then the way to go. I'm sure that is explained in many books.

@JyrkiLahtonen Oh, I will look into what you mentioned, with the Gram-Schmidt, seems more close to what I was asking initially. But bottomline, I need a frame, can't work just with vector N. Thank you so much for taking the time to look into this.
